# Is a Property inverse function if the set of objects in this relation uniquely identifies the subject in OWL?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, functional-dependencies

I have two individuals: x and y. They are in the following relationships:

```
x hasProp a.
x hasProp b.
y hasProp a.
y hasProp c.
```

In general, the set of objects in the realtion of hasProp identifies the individual (here: x or y). In this case, can I say that hasProp is inverse functional, if they have also both one relation which is the same (hasProp a), but the set of hasProp relations uniquely identifies the subject x or y.

Is a Property inverse functional if the set of objects in this relation uniquely identifies the subject in OWL?

Comment: That is literally the definition of inverse functional. Check out the OWL specs on W3C

Comment: That is literally the definition of inverse functional. Check out the OWL specs on W3C

Comment: OWL W3C spec says: "i.e. there cannot be two distinct instances x1 and x2 such that both pairs (x1,y) and (x2,y) are instances of P." However, if x1=x and x2=y  and y=a then hasProp would not be inverse functional because of: (x,a) and (y,a)?!

Comment: If the property is inverse functional, then x is inferred to be sameAs y. The pairs in the relationship are represented replacing sameAs individuals so that 'duplicates' are removed.

Comment: @Ignazio thanks for reply. No, x and y are different individuals. So, it makes no sense to say that hasProp is inverse functional, right?

Comment: If they are distinct individuals, then asserting that the property is inverse functional will cause reasoners to find an inconsistency.